# Mathematical definition of probability current

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Probability currents play a role in Quantum Mechanics and Statistical Mechanics. There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current) on such a concept, where I read

> In quantum mechanics, the probability current (sometimes called probability flux) is a mathematical quantity describing the flow of probability.

I would like to know if there is a related concept with a clean mathematical definition (even an implicit definition) within probability theory. I can find only physics-oriented bibliographies on this subject.

Comment: To have a current, you need a dynamics, so you might not easily find it in basic probability texts. You at least need something about either stochastic differential equations, Markov chains, or more sophisticated. If it's in the context of quantum mechanics, you'll have to look into books on C*-algebras/Von Neumann algebras with attention to dynamics. I don't have any references in mind though.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, you're right that there is a need for dynamics or at least something time-dependent. I am not confined to introductory probability texts. However, even looking at the literature about time-dependent stochastic processes, I have not found traces of something related to probability flow.

Comment: The simplest approach is to take Brownian motion's transition probability which is known to satisfy the heat equation. The latter can be understood as a continuity equation for the probability current. BTW: the WP page you started from is mathematically clean and provides classical (i.e. QM-free) examples and links them all to continuity equations from heat flow or fluid dynamics. I do not think that you need more than a bit of patience to get through.

Comment: @KurtG. I have no problem with that Wikipedia page. However, it does not contain a definition of probability flow. I am not satisfied with the fluid analogy. If, from the math point of view, a probability density is connected to a measure, which mathematical entity is a probability flow connected to?

Comment: To the gradient of the density. [Fick's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion#Fick's_first_law). [Energy and heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation#Energy_and_heat).

Comment: @KurtG. I know Fick's law and heat equation quite well, but it is not something you may find in a textbook on probabilities. You may connect probability density to the measure theory (Radon-Nikodym theorem). What mathematical concepts are connected to probability currents? Maybe the answer is that they are not relevant mathematical concepts. But I am a physicist and not a mathematician. Therefore, I ask the question here.

Comment: Again: the gradient of the density of Brownian *is* the probability current. Do you accept this as mathematical concept? Why do we need a text book if, as you say, you understand it quite well?

Comment: @KurtG. I have no problem with the gradient of the density of Brownian as the probability current. But this is a definition valid for a specific problem. Fick's law does not have general validity. A general definition should contain it as a special case and should be based on a conceptual definition of what a probability current is intended to represent. Moreover, there are different interpretations of probability. Is it the same for the currents? Is there a current associated to Bayes' update of probabilities? I think that a better understanding of the current than *the gradient* is needed.

Comment: If you think the world needs that you have an obvious research topic now.